I can't save my trained model using Pyspark
I'm new to pyspark, I trained a model using linear regression and other using logistic regression but both i face the same problem, at the end I can't save the model .pkl or as a folder, I used google collab I saved it, but then I can't load it on my laptop,  I tried joblib but no result :
The code:
I am running the following code:
regressor=LinearRegression(featuresCol='Independent Features', labelCol='Yearly Amount Spent')
regressor=regressor.fit(train_data)
regressor.save("lr_model.model")

However, all I get is an empty folder named metadata.
The Error:
And this is the error I am getting:
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o282.save.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:106)
    at   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1089)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    .
    .
    .
      org.apache.spark.ml.regression.InternalLinearRegressionModelWriter.write(LinearRegression.scala:786)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.GeneralMLWriter.saveImpl(ReadWrite.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWriter.save(ReadWrite.scala:168)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: o      rg.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
     at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
     at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:136)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCommitter.commitJob(OutputCommitter.java:291)
     at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
     at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$3(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:552)
     at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:100)
... 52 more

I tried to save a trained model to use it later, I expected to have a folder or a .pkl file, but all I have its an empty folder named metadata
